# Why does IDEA display tabs that contain build.gradle files as workspace dir name?

Tags: intellij-idea, build.gradle

every other tab shows the filename, which would be excellent as I'm looking at a 450 multi project build so in theory I could open 450 files and they all would have the same useless workspace name string in them.   It's not even an option as far as I can tell.

Do you know how make myawsomestuff/myawesomething/build.gradle  not show up as myawesomestuff?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: IDE shows the name of the Gradle project next to the `build.gradle` in a tab title: https://monosnap.com/file/1O8bUvcveuBkBvSjPPd5vMcInlZ563 What is the problem with such naming can you elaborate?

Comment: my ide doesn't show the same, it's simply the parent project folder name.  I can open 450 different build.gradle files and they all have the identical tab title.

Comment: Please include screenshot of what you have including the location of these files in the Project tool window.

Comment: Are you sure these Gradle files were loaded as Gradle modules? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#link_gradle_project